# Tensorflow/Keras: volatile validation loss

Tags: validation, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I've been training a U-Net for single class small lesion segmentation, and have been getting consistently volatile validation loss. I have about 20k images split 70/30 between training and validation sets-so I don't think the issue is too little data. I've tried shuffling and resplitting the sets a few times with no change in volatility-so I don't think the validation set is unrepresentative. I have tried lowering the learning rate with no effect on volatility. And I have tried a few loss functions (dice coefficient, focal tversky, weighted binary cross-entropy). I'm using a decent amount of augmentation so as to avoid overfitting. I've also run through all my data (512x512 float64s with corresponding 512x512 int64 masks--both stored as numpy arrays) do double check that the value range, dtypes, etc. aren't screwy...and I even removed any ROIs in the masks under 35 pixels in area which I thought might be artifact and messing with loss.

I'm using keras ImageDataGen.flow_from_directory...I was initially using zca_whitening and brightness_range augmentation but I think this causes issues with flow_from_directory and the link between mask and image being lost.. so I skipped this.

I've tried validation generators with and without shuffle=True. Batch size is 8.

Here's some of my code, happy to include more if it would help:

```
# loss 

from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf 

epsilon = 1e-5
smooth = 1

def dsc(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return score

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 1 - dsc(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss

def bce_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss

def confusion(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth=1
    y_pred_pos = K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)
    y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
    y_pos = K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)
    y_neg = 1 - y_pos
    tp = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos)
    fp = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_pos)
    fn = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_neg) 
    prec = (tp + smooth)/(tp+fp+smooth)
    recall = (tp+smooth)/(tp+fn+smooth)
    return prec, recall

def tp(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1
    y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))
    y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))
    tp = (K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos) + smooth)/ (K.sum(y_pos) + smooth) 
    return tp 

def tn(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1
    y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))
    y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
    y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))
    y_neg = 1 - y_pos 
    tn = (K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg) + smooth) / (K.sum(y_neg) + smooth )
    return tn 

def tversky(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_pos = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_pos = K.flatten(y_pred)
    true_pos = K.sum(y_true_pos * y_pred_pos)
    false_neg = K.sum(y_true_pos * (1-y_pred_pos))
    false_pos = K.sum((1-y_true_pos)*y_pred_pos)
    alpha = 0.7
    return (true_pos + smooth)/(true_pos + alpha*false_neg + (1-alpha)*false_pos + smooth)

def tversky_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - tversky(y_true,y_pred)

def focal_tversky(y_true,y_pred):
    pt_1 = tversky(y_true, y_pred)
    gamma = 0.75
    return K.pow((1-pt_1), gamma)



    model = BlockModel((len(os.listdir(os.path.join(imageroot,'train_ct','train'))), 512, 512, 1),filt_num=16,numBlocks=4)
    #model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=weighted_cross_entropy)
    #model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=dice_coef_loss)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=focal_tversky)
    train_mask = os.path.join(imageroot,'train_masks')
    val_mask = os.path.join(imageroot,'val_masks')

    model.load_weights(model_weights_path) #I'm initializing with some pre-trained weights from a similar model

     data_gen_args_mask = dict(
        rotation_range=10,
        shear_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.1, 
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        zoom_range=[0.8,1.2],
        horizontal_flip=True,
        #vertical_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest',
        data_format='channels_last'
        )

    data_gen_args = dict(
        **data_gen_args_mask
    )

    image_datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    mask_datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)#_mask)

    image_datagen_val = ImageDataGenerator()
    mask_datagen_val = ImageDataGenerator()

    seed = 1
    BS = 8

    steps = int(np.floor((len(os.listdir(os.path.join(train_ct,'train'))))/BS))
    print(steps)
    val_steps = int(np.floor((len(os.listdir(os.path.join(val_ct,'val'))))/BS))
    print(val_steps)

    train_image_generator = image_datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
         train_ct,
         target_size = (512, 512),
         color_mode = ("grayscale"),
         classes=None,
         class_mode=None,
         seed = seed,
         shuffle = True,
         batch_size = BS)

    train_mask_generator = mask_datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
        train_mask,
        target_size = (512, 512),
        color_mode = ("grayscale"),
        classes=None,
        class_mode=None,
        seed = seed,
        shuffle = True,
        batch_size = BS)

    val_image_generator = image_datagen_val.flow_from_directory(
        val_ct,
        target_size = (512, 512),
        color_mode = ("grayscale"),
        classes=None,
        class_mode=None,
        seed = seed,
        shuffle = True,
        batch_size = BS)

    val_mask_generator = mask_datagen_val.flow_from_directory(
        val_mask,
        target_size = (512, 512),
        color_mode = ("grayscale"),
        classes=None,
        class_mode=None,
        seed = seed,
        shuffle = True,
        batch_size = BS)

    train_generator = zip(train_image_generator, train_mask_generator)
    val_generator = zip(val_image_generator, val_mask_generator)

# make callback for checkpointing

    plot_losses = PlotLossesCallback(skip_first=0,plot_extrema=False)
    %matplotlib inline

    filepath = os.path.join(versionPath, model_version + "_saved-model-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5")

    if reduce:
        cb_check = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath,monitor='val_loss',
                        verbose=1,save_best_only=False,
                        save_weights_only=True,mode='auto',period=1),
                        reduce_lr,
                        plot_losses]
    else:
        cb_check = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath,monitor='val_loss',
                        verbose=1,save_best_only=False,
                        save_weights_only=True,mode='auto',period=1),
                        plot_losses]

# train model
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=numEp,
                    steps_per_epoch=steps,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    validation_steps=val_steps, 
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=cb_check,
                    use_multiprocessing = False
                             )
```

And here's how my loss looks:

[image]

Another potentially relevant thing: I tweaked the flow_from_directory code a bit (added npy to the white list). But training loss looks fine so assuming the issue isnt here

Comment: Guess 1: Although you're using the same seed, you might be getting trolled by using `shuffle=True`. I'd try `False` just in case. ---- Guess 2: you've got `BatchNormalization` layers in your model in one of these cases: a) there are pretrained segments and you set `trainable=False` for these segments ; b) the BN layer is after a `Dropout` layer.

Comment: I initially had shuffle=False for val generators and got the same issues. Printed out layer.trainable for layer in model.layers and got all True except the first layer. No dropout layers in model.summary/model.layers, BN are after conv or deconv only

Comment: I didn't find anything strange in your code, so all I can do is keep trying to guess the problem. -- Even though you say your BNs are ok, you could try to remove the BN layers, and make sure they are "trainable=True" before compilation. ---- Another thing that I can imagine is that your image names are not consistent with the mask names in the val directories. ---- Another guess, maybe you have way too many empty masks in validation (and your loss seems to depend on having a good denominator)

Comment: Hint, you can take `len(train_image_generator)` and `len(val_image_generator)` as number of steps, and also compare the lengths of the other generators

Comment: This would be a lot easier for you, or anyone, to debug if you can first walk through this step by step and confirm that batch-wise this works the way you expect. Outside `model.fit`. Start with: look at the pairs generated by your image loaders: are they paired up properly?

Comment: My guess is that the validation data is consistently different from the training data. 1) Do you apply the same preprocessing to your validation data? What happens when you use the same `data_gen_args` for `image_datagen_val` and `mask_datagen_train`? 2) Are the train/validation sets balanced?

Comment: @mdaust, I ran through with the train_generator and val_generator (x, y = train_generator.__next__() ) and the batches seem to load and pair correctly

Comment: @rvinas, I've tried shuffling the validation and training data differently and rerunning so the raw data shouldn't be the issue. The preprocessing is a little different . I wasn't able to do brightness_range and z_epsilon stuff online so I did some offline augmentation of the training data where I randomly pulled around 1/3rd of the images and did brightness range augmentation. I checked dtype and value range after though and everything matches up..

Comment: @DanielMoller, thanks for all the suggestions, I'll try removing BN layers and adding in for layer in "model.layers[:-layerFreeze]:layer.trainable = True". Naming is consistent between train and val directories. good thought about the empty masks...I've tried raising the alpha in the focal tversky loss but this had little effect, maybe I could go through and randomly delete ~half the image/mask pairs where the masks are empty?

Comment: Is it possible for you to increase the batch size to 16 or even more?

Comment: can't increase the batch size beyond 8 due to memory constraint issues

Comment: It's a little wierd, but anyway, try normalizing the input images by dividing, and then try using just one loss-function without the other, and I recommend binary_crossentropy!! -@user3470496

Comment: I would say that the first thing I would change is to increase the `batch_size` since a very low value such as 8 is quite a rough approximation of the true gradient resulting in a very irregular trajectory towards the minimizer. Don't you have the opportunity to try on a different machine with more memory? Also, I would first try with a standard cross-entropy loss and afterwards try more sophisticated losses.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Switch to the classic validation data format (i.e. numpy array) instead of using a generator -- this will ensure you always use the exactly same validation data every time. If you see a different validation curve, then there is something "random" in the validation generator giving you different data at different epochs.
2. Use a fixed set of samples (100 or 1000 should be enough w/o any data augmentation) for both training and validation. If everything goes well, you should see your network quickly overfit to this dataset and your training and validation curves should very much similar. If not, debug your network.